# How to add and access a yaml file as a resource in Ballerina?

Tags: resources, ballerina

I have a YAML file that I want to keep as part of my jar resources and consume inside my `.bal` program.
I have created a resources folder under my project and placed the file there.
The file is being added to the JAR and I can confirm it.

But how do I now access it within my code:

```
string requestedFile = "./resources/service_openapi.yaml"; // <--- here
res.setFileAsPayload(requestedFile, contentType = mime:APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
```

The above throws a runtime error: no such file or directory

Comment: Just tried this myself and it works without an issue. I did `bal build` first and then `bal run target/bin/<project_name>.jar`. By any chance, are you on windows?

Comment: @imesha did you try running bal run from outside your project root folder?     Your code is probably referring to the yaml file from the OS dir (<project_dir_root>/resources/...) instead of from isnide the jar itseld (<jar>/resources/...)

Comment: Actually yes. I was running it from the project root. It doesn't work from anywhere else.

Comment: I am afraid the resource API is still in the design phase: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/1100. As a workaround, if your yaml is not too large, can you define a string with the yaml content and use it as the payload?

Comment: I can't. the yaml is the openapi spec that I generate for the http service endpoints created in my code `bal openapi -i xxx -o yyy` . So, unfortunatly its not a static piece of text but par of my build process.... Any other workaround?